# Reset textfield after form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a textfield and a button to submit this text field which look like

```
<form action="/library" method='POST'>
    {{ form_add_library_category.name(size=80, class="form-control", id="new_category_field", placeholder='New category', onkeyup="stoppedTyping()", style="height:35px;width:205px;display:inline;") }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary add_button" id="add_category" style="display: inline;margin-top:-3px;height:35px">Add</button>
</form>
```

after the textfield is submitted I would like to set the value of the text field to an empty string and disable the button. I do this in javascript with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add_category").click(function(){ 
        document.getElementById('new_category_field').value = '';
        document.getElementById('add_category').disabled = true;
    });
});
</script>
```

so the form is automatically submitted when the button is clicked. And the javascript part removes the value in the text field and disables the button. However, I noticed that this setup has two possible outcomes. It can be that the javascript is faster, in which case the textfield is set to an empty value and that empty string is submitted with the form. Or the form is faster, in which case everything works as intended. Is there a way to make sure that the javascript function is always executed after the form is submitted?
thanks
carl

EDIT: Build on the current replies I changed my javascript function to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#add_category_form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.submit();

        setTimeout(function(){ // Delay for Chrome
            $('#new_category_field').val('');
            $('#add_category').prop('disabled', true);
        }, 100);
    });
});
</script>
```

which prevents the form from being emptied before submission. Especially Chrome seems to empty the form before submission, so the Timeout seems to be required... even though I don't think it is very nice. Anyway, the setting value to empty string still does not work?

Comment: initially check your event triggers inside '$("#add_category").click(function(){ '. make alert or console to check.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<form action="/library" method="POST" id="form">
...
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.submit();
        $('#new_category_field').val('');
        $('#add_category').prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

Not tested, but I think it should work.

**EDIT:** Just in case, stop the default action, submit the form, and then clear the value.

Comment: thanks for the reply... see edit above for my updates